# Accessing Objective-C block from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks, swift-block

I have this Objective-C code in FileManagerHelper:

```
+(void)getMyVideoObject:(NSString *)videoId completion:(void (^)(MyVideoObject *myVideoObject, NSError *error)) completionBlock
{

}
```

For calling from Objective-C:

```
 [FileManagerHelper getMyVideoObject:videoId completion:^(MyVideoObject *myVideoObject, NSError *error) {

}];
```

But how do I call this getMyVideoObject from Swift?

`FileManagerHelper.getMyVideoObject(` .....?

Comment: Yes, when you import header file into bridge header then Swift will generate Swift version of function signature and you can call it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add into your bridging header (-Bridging-Header.h file generated when you add .swift file to Objective-C project)

```
#import "FileManagerHelper.h"
```

2) In swift code use the following call

```
FileManagerHelper.getMyVideoObject("id") { (video, error) in

}
```

Comment: Did not know in Swift video and error do not need to be declared.  Thanks.